# Align to bottom and center horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have a modal and I wish for the page numbers to be at the bottom of the modal and center aligned.

The page numbers are positioned absolute with bottom 0 and aligned center with text align:

```
#pagination{

  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;  
}
```

The problem is, I make the page numbers 100% width (so they can be center aligned) but this takes in to account the modals padding (I can't change this), so the page numbers are just off center and go off the page.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Csk6J/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `width:100%;` try using

```
#pagination{   
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0; 
    right:0;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/Csk6J/4/)

This way you can add padding to the `#pagination` if you need to

Comment: Thanks but the pagination is no longer center aligned;

Comment: @panthro it is center aligned in the fiddle?  try adding `text-align:center` to `#pagination`, you don't seem to have included that style in your original fiddle but you did in the code in your question

Comment: It should be, perhaps it didnt save, sorry if it wasnt there, is there a way to center align?

Answer (score 6):

try add `left:0;` to you code

```
#pagination {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;/*add this*/
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the pagination is no longer center aligned

Comment: to align text add text-align: center;

Answer (score 0):

Add `left:0` along with `bottom:0` and `position:absolute` like this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Csk6J/3/)**

**CSS:**

```
#pagination {
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the pagination is no longer center aligned

Answer (score 0):

Add left and right position to 0 and remove width css

```
#pagination{
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Csk6J/5/

Comment: Thanks but the pagination is no longer center aligned